# Trying to Call an Activity from a Surface View (via onTouch)

Tags: android, android-activity, call, surfaceview, ontouch

I've been trying to call an activity from a surface view via On Touch. However, with the code I've constructed (and I've tried all possible trials and errors, I'm a novice programmer fyi), I keep clicking on the surface view and nothing happens.

I badly need some help guys, this is a school project :3

Thanks!

```
package com.projtimesequencesrc;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;

public class SurfaceViewer extends View implements OnTouchListener {

private Context svc;

float x, y;

Bitmap bgd, main;

Bitmap dialog;
Rect dialogsrc, dialogdst;
//dog



Bitmap dog;
Rect dogsrc, dogdst;
Paint p;

//Molly
Bitmap molly;
Rect mollysrc, mollydst;

//Molly2
Bitmap youngstar;
Rect youngstarsrc, youngstardst;

//Bear
Bitmap bear;
Rect bearsrc, beardst;

Thread tbear, tdbear;
Runnable rbear, dbear;

//man1
Bitmap man1;
Rect mansrc, mandst;

// Main Character
Rect bgdst, charsrc, chardst;

Thread tstory, tdstory;
Runnable rstory, dstory;


protected void onDraw (Canvas c) {
    super.onDraw(c);
    bgdst.right=getWidth();
    bgdst.bottom=getHeight();

    c.drawBitmap(bgd, null, bgdst, p);
    c.drawBitmap(main, charsrc,chardst, p);
    c.drawBitmap(dog, dogsrc, dogdst, p);
    c.drawBitmap(bear, bearsrc, beardst, p);
    c.drawBitmap(man1, mansrc, mandst, p);
    c.drawBitmap(dialog, dialogsrc, dialogdst, p);
    c.drawBitmap(molly, mollysrc,mollydst, p);
    c.drawBitmap(youngstar, youngstarsrc, youngstardst, p);

    invalidate();
}


void sqyoungstar2() {

    int count = 0;
    while (true) {
        youngstarsrc.left += 64;
        youngstarsrc.right += 64;
        if (youngstarsrc.left > (64*6)) {
            youngstarsrc.left = 0;
            youngstarsrc.right = 64;
        }

        SystemClock.sleep(200);
        count++;
        if (count > 38) {
            break;
        }
    }

}

void sqyoungstar1() {
    youngstarsrc.left = 0;
    youngstarsrc.right = 64;
    youngstarsrc.top = 64*2;
    youngstarsrc.bottom = 64*3;

    youngstardst.left = 280;
    youngstardst.right = 330;
    youngstardst.top = 200;
    youngstardst.bottom = 250;
    sqyoungstar2();
}




void seq4() {
    // Main Character
    charsrc.left = 0;
    charsrc.right = 64;
    charsrc.top = (64*9);
    charsrc.bottom = (64*10);

    mansrc.left = 0;
    mansrc.right = 64;
    mansrc.top = (64*9);
    mansrc.bottom = (64*10);


    int count = 0;
    while (true) {
        charsrc.left += 64;
        charsrc.right += 64;
        if (charsrc.left > (64*8)) {
            charsrc.left = 0;
            charsrc.right = 64;
        }

        chardst.offset(-5, 0);
        SystemClock.sleep(100);
        count++;
        if (count > 38) {
            break;
        }
    }
    SystemClock.sleep(1000);
}


void seq3() {
    // Main Character


    charsrc.left = 0;
    charsrc.top = (64*11);
    charsrc.right= 64;
    charsrc.bottom = (64*12);
    SystemClock.sleep(3000);
    seq4();
}

void seq2() {
    // Main Character
    int count = 0;


    while (true) {
    charsrc.left += 64;
    charsrc.right += 64;
    if (charsrc.left > (64 * 6)) {
        charsrc.left = 0;
        charsrc.right = 64;
    }
    chardst.offset(5, 0);
    SystemClock.sleep(100);
    count++;
    if (count > 38) {
        break;
    }

}

seq3();


}

void sequence1() {
    // main character

    dialogsrc.left = 0;
    dialogsrc.right = 536;
    dialogsrc.top = 0;
    dialogsrc.bottom = 120;

    dialogdst.left = 100;
    dialogdst.right = 736;
    dialogdst.top = 50;
    dialogdst.bottom = 170;

    charsrc.left = 0;
    charsrc.top = (64*11);
    charsrc.right= 64;
    charsrc.bottom = (64*12);

    chardst.left = 192;
    chardst.top = 255;
    chardst.right= 256;
    chardst.bottom = 315;


    mansrc.left = 0;
    mansrc.right = 64;
    mansrc.top = (64*3);
    mansrc.bottom = (64*4);

    mandst.left = 150;
    mandst.right = 214;
    mandst.top = 255;
    mandst.bottom = 315;

    SystemClock.sleep(2000);
    seq2();
}


void sqdog4() {
    dogsrc.left = 0;
    dogsrc.right = 80;
    dogsrc.top = 0;
    dogsrc.bottom = 80;

    SystemClock.sleep(2000);
}

void sqdog3() {
    dogsrc.left = 80;
    dogsrc.right = 80*2;
    dogsrc.top = 80;
    dogsrc.bottom = 80*2;

    SystemClock.sleep(2000);

    sqdog4();
}

void sqdog2() {
    int count = 0;
    while (true) {
    dogsrc.left +=80;
    dogsrc.right +=80;

    if (dogsrc.left > (80*2)) {
        dogsrc.left = 0;
        dogsrc.right = 80;
    }

    SystemClock.sleep(100);
    count++;
    if (count > 28) {
        break;
    }

    }
    SystemClock.sleep(5000);
    // insert sequence
    sqdog3();
}

void sqdog1() {
    dogsrc.left = 0;
    dogsrc.right = 80;
    dogsrc.top = 0;
    dogsrc.bottom = 80;

    dogdst.left = 470;
    dogdst.right = 535;
    dogdst.top = 280;
    dogdst.bottom = 315;
    sqdog2();
}


void sqbear2() {
    int count = 0;
    while (true) {
        bearsrc.left+= 56;
        bearsrc.right+=56;

        if (bearsrc.left > 56) {
            bearsrc.left = 0;
            bearsrc.right = 56;
        }

        SystemClock.sleep(100);
        count++;
        if (count > 14) {
            break;
        }
    }
    SystemClock.sleep(2000);
}

void sqbear1() {
    bearsrc.left = 0;
    bearsrc.right = 56;
    bearsrc.top = (56*4);
    bearsrc.bottom = (56*5);

    beardst.left = 600;
    beardst.right = 656;
    beardst.top = 260;
    beardst.bottom = 316;
    sqbear2();
}

public SurfaceViewer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    bgdst = new Rect();
    charsrc = new Rect();
    chardst = new Rect();
    dogsrc = new Rect();
    dogdst = new Rect();
    bearsrc = new Rect();
    beardst = new Rect();

    dialogsrc = new Rect();
    dialogdst = new Rect();

    mansrc = new Rect();
    mandst = new Rect();

    mollysrc = new Rect();
    mollydst = new Rect();

    youngstarsrc = new Rect();
    youngstardst = new Rect();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    main = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), 
            R.drawable.moviemysterycharacter);
    bgd = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.background);
    dog = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.dog);
    bear = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.differentbears);
    man1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.man1);

    dialog = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.dialog1);

    molly = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.auntmollu);
    youngstar = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.auntmollu);

    p = new Paint();
    rstory = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while(true) {
                sequence1();
            }
        }
    };
    tstory = new Thread(rstory);
    tstory.start();

    dstory = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while(true) {
                sqdog1();
            }
        }
    };
    tdstory = new Thread(dstory);
    tdstory.start();


    dbear = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            while(true) {
                sqbear1();
            }
        }
    };
    tbear = new Thread(dbear);
    tbear.start();

    dbear = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                sqyoungstar1();
            }
        }
    };
    tbear = new Thread(dbear);
    tbear.start();


}





@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent i = new Intent(svc, SecondAct.class);


    switch (me.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        svc.startActivity(i);
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        svc.startActivity(i);
        break;  
    }


    return true;


}
```

}

Comment: Any error in logcat? Probably `Context svc` is `null` not initialized...

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [getContext()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getContext()) instead of svc.